# Word Wrap via Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, complexity, dynamic-programming

[Word Wrap problem](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-GA.1170-003/TextAlignment.pdf) in short:

> Given n words and a line length, break the words into lines in such a manner that minimizes the sum of the costs of all the lines. Consider the cost of each line being (free space in the line)^2.

I'm supposed to implement an algorithm with \$O(n)\$ time complexity and \$O(n^2)\$ space complexity. The way I see mine is \$O(n^2)\$ in time and \$O(n^3)\$ in space, but when looking for better solutions I found people describing the same procedure I followed as  \$O(n)\$ and \$O(n^2)\$. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200593/implementing-text-justification-with-dynamic-programming) and in the full description of the problem linked above.

Are they simply ignoring the cost of calculating the penalty cost of each line (they call it "badness" and I "cost")? Because inside their main \$O(n^2)\$ loop they call the badness function that contains a \$O(n)\$ loop inside. Am I supposed to take into account only the cost of the dynamic programming part? If not, what am I doing effectively different? How could I improve it?

```
using namespace std;

// all vectors start to be filled in 1
void solve(vector<string> words, int line_width){
    int i, j, k;
    int n = words.size() - 1;  // number of words
    int opt[n+1]; // opt[j] = min cost for a text ending in words[j]
    int cost[n+1][n+1]; // cost[i][j] cost of adding a line from words[i] to words[j]
    int parent[n+1]; // parent[j] = i means that the optimal line ending in j starts in i

    // fills cost  
    for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        for(j = i; j <= n; ++j){
            int filled = j-i; // number of spaces added between words i and j
            for(k = i; k <= j; ++k){
                filled += words[k].length(); 
            }
            if(filled > line_width){ 
                cost[i][j] = INF; // if such a line is not possible
            } else {
                cost[i][j] = (line_width - filled) * (line_width - filled);
            }   
        }
    }

    // fills opt
    opt[0] = 0;
    for(j = 1; j <= n; ++j){
        opt[j] = INF;
        for(i = 1; i <= j; ++i){
            if(opt[i-1] + cost[i][j] < opt[j]){ 
                opt[j] = opt[i-1] + cost[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // prints solution backwards (because of the order 'parent' was filled)
    int end = n; 
    string solution = "";
    while(end > 0){
        solution = words[end] + '\n' + solution; 
        for(i = end - 1; i >= parent[end]; --i){
            solution = words[i] + ' ' + solution;
        }
        end = parent[end] - 1;
    }
    cout << solution;
}
```

Comment: I think you should read [this webpage](http://xxyxyz.org/line-breaking/), which is full of good ideas and sample implementations.